# What does "as Jesus did" mean in 1 John 2:6?

Tags: jesus, historical-interpretation, 1-john, authorial-intent

In **1 John 2:6 NIV**, it says that

> 6 Whoever claims to live in him must live as Jesus did.

What is the meaning of this verse in general, but more specifically the part of living "as Jesus did"? Jesus officially left home at around the age of 30 and preached the gospel or rather, *"Repent, for the kingdom of God is at hand"*; he also didn't have much money and wandered with his disciples from house to house. Does this mean that no one is living as Jesus did? Other explanations could possibly be live in the spirit of Jesus's actions, but this doesn't exclude compassion towards the poor, widowed, and orphans as I see many of fellow churchgoers ignoring them (at my church at least). For it is written,

> 26 Those who consider themselves religious and yet do not keep a tight rein on their tongues deceive themselves, and their religion is worthless. 27 Religion that God our Father accepts as pure and faultless is this: to look after orphans and widows in their distress and to keep oneself from being polluted by the world. **James 1:26-27 NIV**

Okay, besides that little explication, essentially, my question what was John trying to say when he wrote the phrase, "live as Jesus did"?

If there is anything wrong with this question, please let me know in the comments section and provide something I can do to make it better.

Comment: I would say that anyone who follows Jesus Christ should live _in the manner_ he lived whilst he was on earth. In one's own circumstances, in one's own country, in one's own abilities - one can "walk as he walked" (as the KJV puts it).

Answer (score 2):

John uses the word περιπατεο *peripateo* [Strong 4043](https://biblehub.com/greek/4043.htm) 'to walk around' or, figuratively (see the link) to :

> make one's way, to make progress

One walks through life, going here and there, making progress in one's path.

*How* one walks, *how* one goes through this life is a question of what motivates one.

I would say that the Apostle John is telling us that anyone who follows Jesus Christ should live *in the manner* he lived whilst he was on earth. In one's own circumstances, in one's own country, in one's own abilities - one can "walk as he walked" (as the KJV puts it).

He attended synagogue, he 'was wont' to stand and read out the scripture, he was subject to his parents, he knew the scriptures and quoted them.

Jesus knew how to make a fire on the seashore and how to cook fish. He was approachable - for even little children did not object to him picking them up in his arms. (And children are fussy about who picks them up.)

He made provision for his mother, shortly before his decease.

Jesus wept at the death of a friend. He groaned in his spirit in the presence of mourning.

He thirsted and asked for water and did not shun the Samaritan woman at the well, the way Jews normally treated Samaritans.

He also granted the request of the Syro-Phenician woman, although he had to make a point about the necessary transition period as the gospel went to the Jews first. Yet, still he granted her the wish. (And had travelled all the way up there especially to do it, it seems to me.)

Jesus went about doing good.

When mocked, spat on, buffeted, blindfolded and beaten about the head with a wooden rod, he did . . . .  absolutely nothing, despite that he had the ability to call upon angelic forces to come to his rescue.

Those who, unlawfully, crucified him, without any proper legal process whatsoever, he forgave. Father forgive them, for they know not what they do.

I could go on . . . the four gospel accounts are full of what Jesus did, and all of it can inspire one to walk as he walked in this present, evil world.

Answer (score 1):

I think we need to stay within the context that these words were written.

1 John 2: 3-11 (KJV):

> 3 And hereby we know that we know Him: if we keep His commandments. 4
>   He that saith, “I know Him,” and keepeth not His commandments, is a
>   liar and the truth is not in him. 5 But whoso keepeth His Word, in him
>   verily is the love of God perfected: hereby know we that we are in
>   Him. 6 He that saith that he abideth in Him, ought himself also so to
>   walk, even as He walked. 7 Brethren, I write no new commandment unto
>   you, but an old commandment which ye have had from the beginning. The
>   old commandment is the Word which ye have heard from the beginning. 8
>   Again, a new commandment I write unto you, which thing is true in Him
>   and in you, because the darkness is past and the true light now
>   shineth. 9 He that saith he is in the light and hateth his brother, is
>   in darkness even until now. 10 He that loveth his brother abideth in
>   the light, and there is no occasion for stumbling in him. 11 But he
>   that hateth his brother is in darkness, and walketh in darkness, and
>   knoweth not whither he goeth, because that darkness hath blinded his
>   eyes.

Verses 3-5 say that if you know Christ then you will keep His word/commands and that's how we'll know if we are "in Him".  6 says that if someone says that he abides in Christ (ie, "in Him") then that person should abide in Christ the way Christ abides in the Father and that would be to keep His commands. According to the rest of the verses, the only command that Christ gave to was to love your neighbor has yourself.